# JavaScript call() function

Tags: javascript

I've started learning pure JS by John Resig's book and found quite unclear example with call() function:

```
function forEach (list, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        callback.call(list[i],i)
    };
}

var strings = [ 'hello', 'world', '!'];

forEach(strings, function(index){
    console.log(strings[index]);
});
```

How it works? Can anybody explain?

Comment: How much do you know about call? i.e. what's your starting point? Have you read the documentation, e.g. on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)? The first argument to call is the `this` pointer for your method and the second (and subsequent) are the ones that gets passed to your function as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `call` method is used to invoke a function in a particular context (in other words, with a specific value for `this`). That example invokes the `callback` function in the context of the current list item, and passes in the value of `i`:

```
forEach(strings, function(index){
    console.log(this); // "String ['hello']" etc...
    console.log(index); // "0" etc...
});
```

If the `callback` function was invoked normally (without the `call` method) then the context would be either the global object or `undefined` (if the code is running in strict mode).